# What is the maximum size in a masstransit message?

Tags: c#, masstransit

Pretty much self explanatory. I was sending some message and it sent the error that the message was too big. What is the maximum message size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends upon the message transport, each has its own limitations on message size.

From a guidance perspective, messages over 64k can really slow down broker performance, messages over 256k are a definite no for many systems.

| Transport | Limit |
| --- | --- |
| RabbitMQ | unlimited |
| Azure Service Bus | 256 KB for standard, 1 MB for premium |
| ActiveMQ | unlimited |
| SQS | 256 KB |
| Kafka | 1 MB |
| Azure Event Hub | 1 MB |

Larger messages will affect overall system performance, so keep that in mind. For instance, putting 1 MB messages in RabbitMQ will significantly hurt performance, even more so if using HA/quorum queues.

MassTransit supports the claim check pattern via [Message Data](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/message-data.html) to store large payloads outside of the message body.

Comment: Is it right to say that if you use MessageData the max for the MessageData Threshold would be something slightly below those values since the message size should include metadata ? I think MT supports data payload up to ~252KiB on SQS/Azure but as you said you may not want to exceeds 64KiB in practice. 
The specs I'm working with first wanted 2MiB for Threshold but we will surely lower this value according to your advice :)

Comment: Azure Service Bus now supports 100mb for Premium.

Comment: Which, is, absolutely pointless and a horrible idea, but hey, give the customers what they want right?